# Wifi network not showing up

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have a weird problem, and internet isn't really helpful on that one.

I have a macbook pro and a wifi network. The macbook pro can see plenty of wifi network around, but very rarely mine.

The wifi network is configured properly as I have plenty of other device seeing it and using it successfully. The macbook pro seems to have issue with this network specifically, as it can connect successfully other network.

My network isn't completely invisible to the macbook pro, and, once connected it work fine. The signal strength is very good. But most of the time, it simply don't show up in network lists, possibly for hours.

Answer (score 2):

MacBook Pro supports `802.11n` wifi wireless networking. There are other wifi protocols like `802.11b` and `802.11g`. MacBook Pro is compatible with these (b and g) as well. Wifi issues prop up when your router supports other frequency and your laptop is trying to catch other frequency.

If your router supports 802.11b/g and compatible with `n` then it means some communication problem may arise between your wifi router and your laptop. Best thing that can be done here is to tell your router that it should send signal (broadcast) only on 802.11n.

Go to your wifi router settings (you need to connect your router to your laptop through cable for this. You can consult wifi router help book for this) and Fix channel as `11` (11 from 802.11 is called channel) and bandwidth as 150Mbps. `n` means it will run on 150Mbps. (generally `b` means 54 Mbps and `g` means 65 Mbps). Save your setting and you are hopefully ready to run without any hassle.

PS: You can do the same setting if your wifi is not visible or your MacBook Pro doesn't detect your home wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 5GHz(N network)? I had similar issues when connecting to N-network of different manufacture. I had called Apple regarding this for tech support, they gave me a solution which worked for few days. You can try this, create a new profile/location for network in settings and join to the network.

> http://homepage.ntlworld.com/tg.online/osx/new_location/html/new_location01.html

Well I had bought a timecapsule for backup, i reconfigured my network by connecting timecapsule with old router using lan cable and my computer connects timecapsule for backup & also internet. If you have timecapsule/ or any apple wifi device you can use this type of network to solve it.

Strange thing is I can see and connect to 5GHz (timecapsule) without any problem but not my original router (Netgear).

Comment: This is a plain old 2,4 GHz network. linksys device which is know to work well.